# Why window.location javascript always reload

Tags: javascript, php

today i have a problem with my code, when i test my code, its work but why the page always reload constanly.

```
<body onload="getLocation()">
  <script>
    function getLocation() {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(redirectToPosition);
    }
    function redirectToPosition(position) {
      window.location = '?lat=' + position.coords.latitude + '&long=' + position.coords.longitude;
    }
  </script>
  <?php
  echo  $lat = (isset($_GET['lat'])) ? $_GET['lat'] : '';
  echo $long = (isset($_GET['long'])) ? $_GET['long'] : '';
```

i run my code when the page on load, so i hope somebody can help where the mistake of my code, thanks.

Comment: It reloads constantly because setting `window.location` loads a different page and you do that unconditionally on every load. Try using `if` statements or find an alternative to loading a page with URL parameters, e.g. the [History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/replaceState).

Answer (score 0):

You're calling the `getLocation()` function every time the `<body>` loads.

The function `getLocation()` has a `redirectToPosition` in it, which is the name of your other function.
This functions set's the `window.location`, which forces the page to reload.

If you want to get the current URL, use `var currentLocation = window.location.href;`